# Как правильно имитировать нажатие клавиши или мыши в фоновом приложении через User32.dll?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Пытался имитировать нажатие клавиши в фоновом окне через метод SendMessage библиотеки User32.dll, или через nuget-пакеты PInvoke.User32, Dapplo.Windows.User32. Но, к сожалению, не получается имитировать нажатие клавиши в свернутом/фоновом окне. Получается только имитировать нажатие клавиши через команду SendInput не в фоновом окне. В чем может быть проблема? Пример кода [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913251/why-is-the-method-sendmessage-from-user32-dll-not-working).

Comment: Дайте угадаю - это игра. Если да, то ничего не выйдет, нет технической возможности. Десяток вопросов с точно такой же проблемой я здесь уже видел.

Comment: @aepot вроде как можно покопать в сторону винАпи PostMessage и SendMessage. Но я не в курсе можно ли в игре их использовать

Comment: @Russso покопай в эту сторону  https://github.com/EasyAsABC123/Keyboard

Comment: @aepot Вообще да, я планирую использовать библиотеку для написания бота в игре, но я тестировал и на Notepad++, результат аналогичный.

Comment: В любом случае, с игрой в свернутом режиме ничего не получится. Только в развернутом.

Comment: Не знаю, я использую драйвер на C++, без winapi, он прекрасно работает, даже в играх где winapi блокнут
Вам обязательно WinApi?

Comment: @Yotic Нет, мне главное, чтобы можно возможно было писать используя c# и функционал библиотеки позволял имитировать нажатие клавиш и кликов + возможностью получения изображения с экрана за короткий промежуток времени. Что за драйвер?

Comment: https://github.com/Nekiplay/MacrosAPI-v2